# Wrong Version Number submitted to apple

Tags: ios, app-store, version, app-store-connect

I've been trying to submit an app update with version 1.7.1 to the appstore.
When I do so I get this error on validation

> This bundle is invalid. The key CFBundleShortVersionString in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously uploaded version.

While deleting my failed attempts in the organizer I noticed that the 1.7 update was submitted as version 17!

Bingo!

So the question is this.

Is there a way to fix this? Or am I stuck using versions greater than 17 now?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I would imagine that you are stuck with V17. Perhaps contact apple on the matter?

Comment: no, there is no way to fix it. you have a new version of you application: `17`. it is dead end, try to live with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you should use version greater than 17. You shouldn't contact Apple for that issue.