# Error: This bundle is invalid?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [2.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [2.0]"

**My Earlier version was** 
[image]

**My current, which I am trying to upload is**
[image]

What is issue with Apple. 2.0 is greater than 1.1, why is it happening?

Comment: from my perspective `2.0` is equal to `2.0`... you should update that to e.g. `2.0.1` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time when updating existing iOS Application we must follow this things :

- Every time when updated Application you must have to increase version number
- for example :

> Previous version : 2.0
>
> New version : 2.1 or 3.0

- You can keep build no as it is like 1.0

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

You should increase the Version value aswell (ex. Version 2.01 Build 2)

Comment: Why do I need to upload another version for changing build? What if someone wants to change only build? Thats not natural. waiting for right answer.

Comment: From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH38-SW5): "When you upload a build for the app, iTunes Connect extracts its prerelease version number and build number from the build." Your build number corresponds to the one you  provided via xCode?

Comment: reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526971/wrong-version-number-submitted-to-apple?rq=1) could be that 1.1 is considered 11 then is > than 2. Try with 2.0 or 2.1

Comment: awesome! glad it helped =)

Comment: Sorry, not working fine, I updated comment, I tried both of them already.

Comment: `2.01` = `2.1`, and those are not equal to `2.0.1`

Comment: by this, 2.0.1.1 will be 2.11, while I am putting 2.0.2.0, means 2.20, still my new version is bigger than previous

Comment: uhm... and what about 1.2?

Comment: @SamShaikh, `2.0.1.1` is never going to be `2.11`.

Comment: 1.2 will work, I am sure, as last time it was 1.0, it was not taking 2.0 as build, than I uploaded 1.1.